# TinyMCE inline toolbar insert image issue

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have got tinyMCE 5 installed and working, I have got a custom image upload working as in Image 2, I am having issue with the inline toolbar shortcuts as in image 1. I would prefer to deactivate this toolbar. If that fails how can i get this insert image to upload like that in image 2 and not as a base64 encode image.

[1. Image Upload Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAWaY.png)
[2. Inline toolbar for insert image and table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKX8B.png)

All of this work except that inline toolbar, Any suggestions on removing it.

My Code

```
tinymce.init({
                  selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
                  plugins: 'print preview fullpage    searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality  visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media  codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists  wordcount   imagetools textpattern noneditable help    charmap   quickbars  emoticons',
                  menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table help',
                  toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist  | forecolor backcolor casechange  formatpainter removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | fullscreen  preview save print | insertfile image  media link anchor codesample | ltr rtl | showcomments addcomment',
                  image_advtab: true,
                  height: 500,
                    entity_encoding: "raw",

                    content_css: [
                        "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i"
                    ],
                    browser_spellcheck: true,
                    relative_urls : true,
                    forced_root_block : "p",
                    media_poster: false,
                    image_title: true,
                    automatic_uploads: false,
                    paste_data_images: false,


                    images_upload_url: '/uploads/',

                    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
                        var xhr, formData;

                        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.withCredentials = false;
                        xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php');

                        xhr.onload = function() {
                            var json;

                            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                                failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                                return;
                            }

                            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                            if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                                failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                                return;
                            }

                            success(json.location);
                        };

                        formData = new FormData();
                        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

                        xhr.send(formData);
                    }



                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin responsible for the left inline popup is called [quickbars](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/quickbars/). All you have to do is to remove it from the list of your enabled plugins in the configuration object.